# Open a Angular Material Dialog after an leaflet on("click", function()) action

Tags: angular, angular-material, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I want to open an Angular Material Dialog when I click on a leaflet circle.
The Dialog appears but with strange behavior. This strange behavior doesn't appear when I open the Dialog with a normal Button (click) event.

[image: Strange behavior]

I try to call the function like this. I bind an onClickCircles function to my circle.

```
let line = L.circle(latlngEx, { radius: this.circles[i].radius }).on(
          "click",
          this.onClickCircles.bind(this)
        );
```

and when the circle is pressed I open the dialog

```
onClickCircles(e) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MarkerdetailComponent, {
      width: "300px",
      data: { event: e, collection: "circles" }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log("closed")
    });
    //this.deleteCircles(e.target);
  }
```

When call onClickCircle(e) from anywhere else, it works fine. I guess because .bind(this) instantiates my component again and it hast to load the whole component before the dialog appears correct. But I am not sure of this and don't know if there is a work around.

Comment: Things like this often happen when 1) a module isn't being loaded properly or 2) a runtime error is happening (often due to DOM not being rendered before attempting to style). Many times this can be fixed by setting OnInit items to AfterViewInit. It will be difficult to pinpoint the exact error beyond this unless you can provide a StackBlitz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Error happens because the code inside the click function is not executed in an Angular context. It can be fixed by using NgZone.

```
let line = L.circle(latlngEx, { radius: this.circles[i].radius }).on(
          "click",
          e => {
            this.zone.run(() => {
              this.onClickCircles(e)
              })
          }
        );
```